# Fast data sync against DB table from csv

Tags: database, hadoop, merge, apache-spark

I have a nightly process that takes around 18 hours to run. The gist of the operation is that an up-stream service is polled, the data then is applied to my own database - not as 1-to-1, but massaged, compared and snapshotted if necessary (so there's comparison, and bit of other functions involved in going form flat-files into a relational structure).

The upstream has agreed to provide us with a single, rather large csv file nightly, cutting out on the polling times.

I'm thinking of using Spark/hdfs to distribute this process of nightly sync/merge. However I'm wondering how best to do this? Since my own database will get hammered if I query it frequently to compare, insert, etc.

What is the best approach in this case? I've thought about downloading my own data into memory along with the upstream data to make the comparisons faster, but with these databases growing rapidly on a monthly bases, I need a scalable approach.

Answer (score 0):

My proposal:
1, Extract primary key from large CSV file and your database and save them into seperated key files K1, K2;
2, In-memory compare K1 and K2 using spark and calculate out insert/update flag for K1 set, output is (k1, insert/update flag);  also update K2 to speed up next calculation;
3, Insert/update database with optimized approach.

Compare process(step 2) is very resouce consuming for database. Moving it to big data platform will alleviate database presure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The issue is, the upstream primary keys and our local primary keys are completely different - simply because the data is stored in different structures. So comparisons happen on composite keys of sorts, where to validate a tuple, we compare all parameters of the tuples. What to do when you have whole tuples to compare? How to be memory efficient?